# VHDL Design - Clock

Tags: vhdl

Can someone please help me with the following:

Design a digital circuit, using VHDL, to keep track of time in the form of HH:MM:SS. The circuit should produce 6 separate four bit digital outputs (2 four bit outputs for the HH, 2 for the MM, 2 for the SS). The HH can just be a 2 digit number in the range 00 to 99 i.e. it’s not a clock, it just a counter for hours even though 99 hour tapes don’t exist. The time is to be displayed on the 6 right most 7 segment displays of the DE2. You have already designed a 7 segment decoder and driver as part of a previous lab, so that can be used to convert each 4 bit output into a 7 bit signal for each the 7-segment display. Don’t forget to set up the pin planer for these display (and all other signals)

The circuit should have the following single bit inputs: A Clock, an increment, a decrement and a reset. The increment/decrement inputs should cause the tape counter to add or subtract 1 second from the tape time on the next rising edge of the clock signal. If neither the increment or decrement inputs are present, the tape counter does not change. The reset is synchronous to the clock (to avoid glitches accidentally resetting it). The increment and decrement signals are all active high signals (i.e. a logic 1), the reset is active low (logic 0).

You tape counter should handle full hour, minute and second roll over, e.g. if the counter is showing 9:59:59, then the next increment should make it display 10:00:00 and vice versa when decrement is present.

Comment: Please reply as soon as possible!

Comment: Smells like a homework. Welcome to StackOverflow. It's a great place to ask advice, help and find solution to your problem. Do not expect people to do your homework. Show us what you have tried and seek for help or advice.

Comment: I do not understand how to do the question at all. That's why there is no code posted up there

Comment: I would first start by designing the counters. When you confirmed that they work using e.g. modelsim you can chain them together and connect their outputs to the 7 segment displays, using the deocder you already have (according to the text).  
  
The tricky part is to get them to overflow all on the same clock edge, this can be done for example using asynchronous overflow.

Comment: If you have no idea about how to start, it sounds like you are trying to leapfrog initial VHDL learning and understanding.  If this is the case, then start at [Wikipedia VHDL page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl), and at [Further reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl#Further_reading).

To get a simulator that can compile and simulate VHDL, you can use ModelSim-Altera Starter Edition, which is free.  You can get it at [ModelSim-Altera Edition Software](http://www.altera.com/products/software/quartus-ii/modelsim/qts-modelsim-index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than solving your homework, I'd like to give you an idea. Most designers will tend to implement this clock using digit-by-digit rollover (some digits will rollover from 9-0, others from 5-0). I'd like to propose someting different.

The overall idea is: keep your time value in seconds as an integer. This will greatly facilitate the tasks of incrementing and decrementing. Then, you simply implement a conversion function that returns the number of hours, minutes, and seconds, given an integer number of seconds.

Your clock entity would look like this:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.clock_pkg.all;

entity clock is
    port (
        clock: in std_logic;
        n_reset: in std_logic;
        increment: in std_logic;
        decrement: in std_logic;
        hours: out natural range 0 to 99;
        minutes: out natural range 0 to 59;
        seconds: out natural range 0 to 59
    );
end;

architecture rtl of clock is
    signal time_in_seconds: natural range 0 to 359999;
begin

    process (clock, n_reset) begin
        if rising_edge(clock) then
            if n_reset = '0' then
                time_in_seconds <= 0;
            elsif increment then
                time_in_seconds <= time_in_seconds + 1;
            elsif decrement then
                time_in_seconds <= time_in_seconds - 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process (time_in_seconds) begin
        (hours, minutes, seconds) <= seconds_to_time_type(time_in_seconds);
    end process;

end;
```

As you can imagine, the workhorse of this solution is the `seconds_to_time_type()` function. You could implement it like this:

```
package clock_pkg is
    type time_type is record
        hours: natural range 0 to 99;
        minutes, seconds: natural range 0 to 59;
    end record;

    function seconds_to_time_type(seconds: in natural) return time_type;
end;

package body clock_pkg is

    function seconds_to_time_type(seconds: in natural) return time_type is
        variable hh: natural range 0 to 99;
        variable mm: natural range 0 to 119;
        variable ss: natural range 0 to 119;
    begin
        hh := seconds / 3600;
        mm := (seconds mod 3600) / 60;
        ss := (seconds mod 3600) mod 60;
        return (hh, mm, ss);
    end;

end;
```

Now you have an entity that outputs separate integer values for hours, minutes, and seconds. Converting those values from integers to BCD, and showing those values on the displays is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Modulo and division by something not a power of 2 is not synthesizeable, so while this may work in simulation (behavioral), it is not a valid hardware description. There is a good reason why most designers will implement clock counters using binary coded decimal (BCD). Division in hardware is *very* expensive.

Comment: Design is a process with many competing goals. Area optimization can be one, and clarity of design may be another. Altera's synthesis tools have no problem synthesizing the suggested solution, and it takes less than 5% of the smallest FPGA in the Cyclone V family. This is nothing personal, but I am finishing an analyisis of over 500 thousand lines of VHDL code, and if the designers have erred too much on any side, it would be on committing too many atrocities in the name of "optimization" or dubious performance gains, sometimes rendering the code utterly unreadable.

Comment: A common problem for beginners using VHDL is that they try to program a hardware design, rather than describe it. While using such high-level constructs may lead to *code* that is easier to understand, it leads to hardware that is anything but. Given your suggested calculation of hours, minutes and seconds, Quartus requires no less than 2 divide and 2 modulo megablocks (admittedly I was wrong and the code *is* synthesizable), with a maximum frequency of 36Mhz in a C2 Stratix V, and basically no way to optimize it. That is not something I would want in my non-behavioral hardware design.

Comment: 36 MHz should be enough to implement a clock that counts up once every second

Comment: @zennehoy: without a target LUT count and clock speed specified I would say rick has exactly the right approach.  Describe the behaviour that's required want - if it meets spec (function, power, size, speed) you're done.  If it doesn't, only *then* start making the code more confusing.

Comment: @MartinThompson Maybe I'm just horrified at the resulting hardware because in practice I have never had a spec that doesn't have tight constraints on power, size and speed. If there's really that much leeway, then sure, such code is fine. I still stand by my point though that using such high-level constructs is not the best way to teach a beginner the basics of hardware design.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way of implementing a counting clock is using binary coded decimal (BCD), where each digit consists of a separate n-bit counter, with a range as needed.

For example, in order to count seconds (from 0-59), you could use something like the following code:

```
process(clk, reset) begin
    if(reset='1') then
        second_tens <= (others=>'0');
        second_ones <= (others=>'0');
    elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
        if(count_en='1') then
            if(second_ones = 9) then
                second_ones <= (others=>'0');

                if(second_tens = 5) then
                    second_tens <= (others=>'0');
                    -- Count up minutes.
                else
                    second_tens <= second_tens + 1;
                end if;

            else
                second_ones <= second_ones + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Minutes and hours can be counted analogously.

Answer (score 1):

You have skipped a step.  You are trying to think about code with just a worded problem statement.  First step is to design the hardware by drawing a block diagram.  Break the problem down into pieces.

Initial partitioning might be Seconds, Minutes, and Hours.  If you are counting in BCD, it you may wish to partition it further digit by digit.  Work out what your hardware is supposed to do.  Draw a picture.  Write code that describes what is in the picture.

At the end of the day, your RTL block diagram is your HDL flow chart.